# Multiple join to exclude results in the first join that are in the second one

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring JPA.
I have a transactions entity, Transaction, that need to be paid. Those payouts are recorded in another payout entity, PayoutTransaction. They are linked with a ManyToMany relation. Sometimes payouts fail and they are retried adding a new PayoutTransaction entry, which usually is OK. I need to get the transactions that have a failed payout but excluding those failed transactions that also have a OK payout, as they have been successfully paid even they failed the first attempt (they have another entry in the PayoutTransaction entity with status OK). I have tried it with a multiple JOIN between both tables but it includes the transactions even when they have an OK payout. (Which, I know, is the expected behaviour) How can I solve this?

```
SELECT distinct t FROM Transaction t JOIN t.payoutTransactions p JOIN t.payoutTransactions p2 where p.status = 'FAILED' and NOT p2.status = 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **EXISTS** here,

```
SELECT distinct t FROM Transaction t JOIN t.payoutTransactions p
where p.status = 'FAILED' AND exists (SELECT p2
 payoutTransactions p2 where p2.status = p.status and p2.status <> 'OK')
```

Or you could even write a native query as below,

```
SELECT t.* FROM Transaction t join payoutTransaction p on t.ID = p.ID
 where p.status = 'FAILED' AND exists 
(SELECT 1 FROM payoutTransaction p2 where p2.status = p.status and p2.status <> 'OK' )
```

Comment: Hello @Govind. Shouldn't this be "AND NOT exists..." given I want to get the payout FAILED that don't have an OK payout?